# How to make a table of a certain kind

Tags: tables

How can I make a table like those on p. 27 and p. 38 of http://users.ox.ac.uk/~cpgl0036/pdf/asudeh-giorgolo-perspectives.pdf   ?

I am using `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`. I wish to know how to construct a table of the kind mentioned in the space between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` below.

I have no idea how to do so,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   


\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

In the past I have used the following template:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   


\begin{document}



    \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
          & NP1 & Copula & NP2  \\
   \hline
   Equative          & referential &  & referential  \\
    Predicational            & referential &  & non-referential   \\
    Specificational           & non-referential  &  & referential    \\
\end{tabular} 

  \end{document}
```

However, I wish to construct a table as in the article above.

Perhaps it would be useful to have some way, for example, of converting a table of the kind I said I usually construct into a table of the kind that is seen in the website mentioned.

Comment: This should be no problem, but do you mind showing us what you have achieved so far? Ideally a MWE.

Comment: I have achieved nothing.

Comment: @user65526, that is not encouraging! How you expect that we can help you? Does `\begin{table}\hrule\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\caption{...}\hrule\end{table}` help you? For more help, you should provide MWE. According to your reputation this should not be problem for you.

Comment: I have now included a MWE of a table that I have constructed in the past. However, I would have no idea how to construct a table of the kind cited on the website. If you knew how to do it, I would like to see. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually don't answer do-it-for-me questions, especially if it comes from an user that has a fairly high reputation (honest talk, a MWE is ***absolutely necessary***). But I guess I can make an exception. Note that I forcefully scaled down the table with `\scalebox`, as it was too big for one `a4` page.

The code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{23pt}

\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
WORD & DENOTATION & TYPE \\ \midrule
\textit{Reza} & $\mathbf{r}_{\sigma}$ & $e$ \\
\textit{Kim} & $\mathbf{k}_{\sigma}$ & $e$ \\
\textit{Dr. Octopus} & $\mathbf{o}_{\sigma}$ & $e$ \\
\textit{Mary Jane} & $\mathbf{mj}_{\sigma}$ & $e$ \\
\textit{Peter Parker} & $\mathbf{pp}_{\sigma}$ & $e$ \\
\textit{not} & $\lambda p. \neg p$ & $t \rightarrow t$ \\
\textit{but} & $\lambda p.\lambda q. p \wedge q$ & $t \rightarrow t \rightarrow t$ \\
\textit{is} & $\lambda x. \lambda y.x = y$ & $e \rightarrow e \rightarrow t$ \\
\textit{punch} & $\lambda o. \lambda s. \mathbf{punch}(s,o)$ & $e \rightarrow e \rightarrow t$ \\
\textit{believe} & $\lambda c. \lambda s. \mathbf{B}(s,c(\kappa (s)))$ & $\Diamond t \rightarrow e \rightarrow t$ \\
\textit{love} & $\lambda o. \lambda s. \mathbf{love}(s,o(\kappa (s)))$ & $\Diamond e \rightarrow e \rightarrow t$ \\
\textit{Hesperus} &     $\lambda i. = \left\{
                        \begin{array}{ll}
                        \mathbf{es}_{\mathtt{k}}& \text{if }i =\mathtt{k} \\
                        \mathbf{v}_{\sigma}& \text{if } i=\sigma
                        \end{array}
                        \right.$ & $\Diamond e$ \\
\rule{0pt}{8ex}    
\textit{Phosphorus} &   $\lambda i. = \left\{
                        \begin{array}{ll}
                        \mathbf{ms}_{\mathtt{k}}& \text{if }i =\mathtt{k} \\
                        \mathbf{v}_{\sigma}& \text{if } i=\sigma
                        \end{array}
                        \right.$ & $\Diamond e$ \\
\rule{0pt}{8ex}    
\textit{Spider-Man} &   $\lambda i. = \left\{
                        \begin{array}{ll}
                        \mathbf{sm}_{i}& \text{if }i =\mathtt{o} \text{ or } i = \mathtt{mj} \\
                        \mathbf{pp}_{\sigma}& \text{if } i=\sigma
                        \end{array}
                        \right.$ & $\Diamond e$ \\
\rule{0pt}{8ex}    
\textit{Jesus} &    $\lambda i. = \left\{
                    \begin{array}{ll}
                    \mathbf{j}_{\mathtt{r}}& \text{if }i =\mathtt{r} \\
                    \mathbf{j}_{\sigma}& \text{if } i=\sigma
                    \end{array}
                    \right.$ & $\Diamond e$ \\
\rule{0pt}{8ex}    
\textit{Sandy} &    $\lambda i. = \left\{
                    \begin{array}{ll}
                    \mathbf{imp}_{\mathtt{k}}& \text{if }i =\mathtt{k} \\
                    \mathbf{s}_{\sigma}& \text{if } i=\sigma
                    \end{array}
                    \right.$ & $\Diamond e$ \\
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result (P.S.: I'm not going to replicate the second table, as all of the components that you need are already in the first one; furthermore, I derive joy from constructing something myself; let that be your exercise).

[image]

Comment: Nice table, Gregor!  I  use what OP provide ... and really provide a MWE :-)

Comment: Oh thanks! I had some spare time so I played around a bit. From an educational perspective, yours is even better (because you included only basic components for educational purposes). A little question: I feel like my braces are spanning a little too wide; any technique to fix this detail?

Comment: Apologies. I was never aware that 'do-it-for-me' questions were not allowed, and have in fact always and only asked questions basically of this sort (and have received replies). Unfortunately, I don't have the time to read large manuals explaining how to do these things, but if you can suggest a resource where I can quickly learn the basics of table construction that would be great.

Comment: No apologies needed. I remember, the first question I posted on this site was also a do-it-for-me. Everyone needs a little boost to get started, each one of us. There is no shame in posing such a question. I only mentioned it because it's a strict rule that applies to this site. I wish you plenty of fun hours with LaTeX!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is of sort "do-it-for-me", but this site is not such kind of service. You really need to read some introduction literature about LaTeX. Google web will give you a lot of examples, how to design tables ...

You also should show desired form of table in your question. Don't expect, that people here will search web and literature for you.  You should help us to help you ..

Well, see if my comment above can help you:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
%    \hrule
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
    \toprule
                & NP1               & Copula    & NP2               \\
    \midrule
Equative        & referential       &           & referential       \\
Predicational   & referential       &           & non-referential   \\
Specificational & non-referential   &           & referential       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{this is my super very important table with very long description about table content which is broken over many lines}
    \label{table-1}
\hrule
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answers reflect the authors' tastes.  Let me add my version :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false,
  labelfont=bf, labelsep=quad}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\hrulefill\par
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \scshape Word & \scshape Denotation & \scshape Type\\
    \midrule
    \itshape dolphin & $\{\text{\bfseries flipper}_\sigma\}$ & $e\to
    t$\\
    \itshape seal & $\{\text{\bfseries hoover}_\sigma\}$ & $e\to
    t$\\
    \itshape marine mammal & $\lambda i.
    \begin{cases}
      \{\text{\bfseries hoover}_\sigma\} & \quad \text{if $i=e$}\\ 
          \{\text{\bfseries flipper}_\sigma, \text{\bfseries
            hoover}_\sigma\}& 
        \quad \text{if $i=\sigma$} 
\end{cases}
  $
  & $\Diamond e\to t$\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Relevant portion of speaker's lexicon}
\hrulefill
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]